# Firebase: Restrict number of SMS for same phone number or same device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are trying to implement firebase phone auth in our android app as described in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth). It works fine in our app and also the server side validation works as expected. Now we want to add daily number of SMS restriction for same phone number or same device to prevent abuse. The link quotes -

> To prevent abuse, Firebase enforces a limit on the number of SMS messages that can be sent to a single phone number within a period of time. If you exceed this limit, phone number verification requests might be throttled. If you encounter this issue during development, use a different phone number for testing, or try the request again later.

So the questions are -

1. How much is the limit of SMS within how much time for any number?
2. Is there any way from firebase android sdk end to restrict number of SMS for same number or same device.
3. Is there any way from firebase console to restrict number of SMS for same number or same device.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Since this limit is in place to prevent abuse, it is neither fixed nor documented.

There is no way to configure this server-side limit from your code or the console.

As the link says, if you hit the limit during development you should either wait a bit or try with a different phone/number.

If you find that you repeatedly hit this limit during developer, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting or at least to let us know that the limit seems unreasonable for your development practice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually we did not hit the limit during development yet. But we are looking for solutions to restrict real user who try to request too many times for SMS purposefully. We have faced this type of misbehave before when we used digits from fabric, for which our client id was banned without any notice. In digit we did not have anything to do as It was completely their own UI for verification method. So we are looking for solution to restrict this type of misbehave first before deploy in production. Will firebase introduce this type of flexibility in near future? Again thanks

Comment: The limit is non-configurable at the moment. It might be a good candidate for a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). If you ever find your project blocked, your best route is to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.