# Firebase Auth SMS daily quota

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

On the firebase Firebase Auth Dashboard, it shows me this message:

> To prevent abuse, new projects with billing accounts currently have an SMS daily quota of 3,000/day. To increase this quota, please contact Firebase support with details about your needs.

What are cases of "abuse" ? I cannot find them on their terms of use.

Comment: *firebaser here* As said in the answer Monu copy/pasted: "Since this limit is in place to prevent abuse, it is neither fixed nor documented." We've seen various types of abuse and they change over time. Documenting them would make it easier for malicious users to find new abuse vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Since this limit is in place to prevent abuse, it is neither fixed nor documented.

There is no way to configure this server-side limit from your code or the console.

As the link says, if you hit the limit during development you should either wait a bit or try with a different phone/number.

If you find that you repeatedly hit this limit during developer, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting or at least to let us know that the limit seems unreasonable for your development practice.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you are talking about the basic quota. I'm talking about the 3k/day quota, which have no link to errors that you can have during development or when you test multiple time on the same phone number.

Comment: you can use functionality for particular mobile number like time boundation

Comment: @MonuRohilla Please don't copy/paste somebody else's answer as your own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753093/firebase-restrict-number-of-sms-for-same-phone-number-or-same-device. If you think the exact same answer applies here, vote to close the question as a duplicate please.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen ohh thanks for giving me this tip.
i will follow this in future I don't had any idea about it till now am sorry !